# When is available to buy Surface with Windows 8 Pro?

Tags: windows-8, tablet

Based on windows site, it says Surface with Windows 8 Pro coming soon. So question is when it will on the market?

Comment: Is this question valid to be asked on SO? Correct me if I am wrong!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft announced couple months back that Surface pro will be available after 3 months of Surface RT launch. That puts the launch date around late January or early February.

[Surface Pro availability](http://www.itproportal.com/2012/10/29/when-will-microsoft-surface-pro-tablet-launch--what-does-the-delay-mean/)

> The product is expected to be launched approximately 90 days after Windows 8, which points to a February release roughly three weeks after the Consumer Electronics Show which will be the focal point for the tech industry in the first quarter of 2013.